# Chrome extension when to inject JS from background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I have Chrome extension and I'm injecting my app in to a web pages when the tab is loaded.

```
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    // Inject app
```

And sometimes somepages load time is very slow, DOM can be already loaded but some stuff keeps loading and loading, so is there a BETTER time to inject my app?
And how to detect it?

Comment: All web pages? And what does the app do? You're leaving out a lot of information.

Comment: This is just a sidebar. But it does not matter there is a lot of extensions which are injecting something to a webpage to interact with the user.

Comment: Declare a content script in manifest.json instead of doing this.

Comment: @wOxxOm and how do you inject content script in every tab using Manifest v3?

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts